# ViewModel cannot be instantiated in an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I am trying to instantiate one ViewModel to use across all of my Activity(s).

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {
    private Controller control;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);
         control = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Controller.class);
    }
}
```

but I got an error at `control = ViewModelProviders.of(this) <--` stating that it cannot resolve `of(this)`, but based on the example [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#implement) by Android Developer on Implementing ViewModel; a class that extends ViewModel should be able to be instantiated on Activity, am I right?

If what I am doing is wrong, how should I instantiate a ViewModel object for my Activity(s)? Do I have to create `n` number of Activity(s) with Fragment(s) since `ViewModelProviders.of()` only works with Fragment?

Comment: try using AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use the `support library` activity.

`AppCompatActivity` or `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 10):

@elmorabea's Answer was correct, but one important thing to note here is that if you have enabled [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) and are still getting an issue indicating that you need to pass in a fragment instead of an activity, make sure that your class extends the *correct* AppCompatActivity. IE, make sure you are using:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

and not

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

As one is from AndroidX while the other is not. For more info on the AndroidX migrations, see [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) link.

Answer (score 5):

You are extending `Activity`. `ViewModelProviders` works with `FragmentActivity` and things that inherit from that, such as `AppCompatActivity`. It also works with the backport of `Fragment` (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). There is no official support for the native `Activity` or `Fragment` class.

Comment: I am extending from AppCompatActivity. But still it shows the error that "Not able to resolve ViewModelProvider.of()"

Comment: @MudasirRao: You're missing an "s" in ViewModelProviders. If it still doesn't work, make sure your Gradle file contains the dependency, e.g. compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

Comment: You've probably imported `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders` instead of `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders`.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution if you don't want to change your activity to extend from another Activity class (in case your BaseActivity is already used and rely heavily on `Activity` and maybe cause an error if change the parent activity class):

```
@Nullable
private ViewModelStore viewModelStore = null;

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return viewModelStore;
}

@NonNull
private ViewModelStore getViewModelStore() {
    Object nonConfigurationInstance = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (nonConfigurationInstance instanceof ViewModelStore) {
        viewModelStore = (ViewModelStore) nonConfigurationInstance;
    }
    if (viewModelStore == null) {
        viewModelStore = new ViewModelStore();
    }
    return viewModelStore;
}

public ViewModelProvider getViewModelProvider() {
    ViewModelProvider.Factory factory =
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication());
    return new ViewModelProvider(getViewModelStore(), factory);
}
```

This logic is similar to what is in `FragmentActivity`

Then, instead of calling `ViewModelProviders.of(this)`, we just need to call `getViewModelProvider()`. For getting `Controller`:

```
control = getViewModelProvider().get(Controller.class)
```

By doing this, we don't need to add `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` dependency.

Comment: This is a helpful solution. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am using this:

```
 LoginViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
```

Ref:https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java

Answer (score 1):

For me the I was extending `AppCompatActivity`, but still it was not working. But `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'` was missing, adding which it worked fine.